# Undefined Symbols for architecture arm7

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Hello I am having this problem . I have the image for the problem. I am adding UrbanAirship to my cocos2d game. I was not first having this problem but the problem has started right away

Check this image for the problem:
http://i50.tinypic.com/15wxd36.jpg

Any Help would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some frameworks, add `MapKit.framework` and `MessageUI.framework`.

Go to the project in project inspector, Build Phases and select `Link Binary With Libraries`.
The click on the `+` and select both `MapKit.framework` and `MessageUI.framework` and you should be good to go.

Comment: As soon as i solved this i got this problem. Can you help me   http://i50.tinypic.com/ettonb.jpg

Comment: Remove of the two UrbanAirship libraries, use either the push or the full library. You should really have read the [Getting Started: iOS: Push](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%253A+iOS%253A+Push).

Comment: Thousands thanks to you solved the problem because of you.And in the above image i just had the duplicate symbols . Thanks very much you saved my day.

Comment: i have read it before but forgot about removing the other library. i have integrated urban airship before. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks a lot